# Running LLVM optimizer transforms 32bit memory access to 64bits. Is there a way to avoid this?

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir

I am running the llvm optimizer on a piece of llvm-ir code that I am generating. After running the optimizer, memory accesses get translated from 32 bits addresses to 64. I'd like to avoid that as the tool I am using to run the software verification has some problems with 64bits pointers.

This is the original code:

```
target triple = "i386-unknown-linux-gnu"


@Global_0 = local_unnamed_addr global i32 0
@Global_1 = local_unnamed_addr global i32 0
@Global_2 = local_unnamed_addr global i32 0
@Global_3 = local_unnamed_addr global i32 0
@mem = local_unnamed_addr global [128 x i8] zeroinitializer, align 1

define i32 @main() #0  { 

  func_2_entry: 
    %local_0 = alloca i32
    store i32 0, i32* %local_0
    %local_1 = alloca i32
    store i32 0, i32* %local_1
    %local_2 = alloca i32
    store i32 0, i32* %local_2
    br label %box_0

  box_0: 
    %s_0 = load i32, i32* @Global_2, !Stack !{ !"Stack((s_0, W32Int()))" } 
    br label %box_1

  box_1: 
    store i32 %s_0, i32* %local_1, !Stack !{ !"Stack()" } 
    br label %box_2

  box_2: 
    %s_1 = load i32, i32* @Global_2, !Stack !{ !"Stack((s_1, W32Int()))" } 
    br label %box_3

  box_3: 
    %s_2 = add i32 0, 48, !Stack !{ !"Stack((s_2, W32Int()), (s_1, W32Int()))" } 
    br label %box_4

  box_4: 
    %s_3 = add i32 %s_1, %s_2, !Stack !{ !"Stack((s_3, W32Int()))" } 
    br label %box_5

  box_5: 
    store i32 %s_3, i32* @Global_2, !Stack !{ !"Stack()" } 
    br label %box_6

  box_6: 
    %s_4 = load i32, i32* %local_1, !Stack !{ !"Stack((s_4, W32Int()))" } 
    br label %box_7

  box_7: 
    store i32 %s_4, i32* %local_2, !Stack !{ !"Stack()" } 
    br label %loop_8

  loop_8: 
    br label %box_9

  box_9: 
    %s_5 = load i32, i32* %local_2, !Stack !{ !"Stack((s_5, W32Int()))" } 
    br label %box_10

  box_10: 
    %s_6 = load i32, i32* %local_0, !Stack !{ !"Stack((s_6, W32Int()), (s_5, W32Int()))" } 
    br label %box_11

  box_11: 
    %s_7 = add i32 0, 2, !Stack !{ !"Stack((s_7, W32Int()), (s_6, W32Int()), (s_5, W32Int()))" } 
    br label %box_12

  box_12: 
    %s_8 = shl i32 %s_6, %s_7, !Stack !{ !"Stack((s_8, W32Int()), (s_5, W32Int()))" } 
    br label %box_13

  box_13: 
    %s_9 = add i32 %s_5, %s_8, !Stack !{ !"Stack((s_9, W32Int()))" } 
    br label %box_14

  box_14: 
    %s_10 = load i32, i32* %local_0, !Stack !{ !"Stack((s_10, W32Int()), (s_9, W32Int()))" } 
    br label %box_15

  box_15: 
    %temp_0 = getelementptr inbounds [128 x i8], [128 x i8]* @mem, i32 0, i32 %s_9, !Stack !{ !"Stack()" } 
    %temp_1 = bitcast i8* %temp_0 to i32*, !Stack !{ !"Stack()" }   
    store i32 %s_10, i32* %temp_1, !Stack !{ !"Stack()" } 
    br label %box_16

  box_16: 
    %s_11 = load i32, i32* %local_0, !Stack !{ !"Stack((s_11, W32Int()))" } 
    br label %box_17

  box_17: 
    %s_12 = add i32 0, 1, !Stack !{ !"Stack((s_12, W32Int()), (s_11, W32Int()))" } 
    br label %box_18

  box_18: 
    %s_13 = add i32 %s_11, %s_12, !Stack !{ !"Stack((s_13, W32Int()))" } 
    br label %box_19

  box_19: 
    store i32 %s_13, i32* %local_0, !Stack !{ !"Stack()" } 
    br label %box_20

  box_20: 
    %s_14 = add i32 0, 5, !Stack !{ !"Stack((s_14, W32Int()), (s_13, W32Int()))" } 
    br label %box_21

  box_21: 
    %s_15 = icmp ne i32 %s_13, %s_14, !Stack !{ !"Stack()" } 
    %s_16 = zext i1 %s_15 to i32
    br label %cond.branch_22

  cond.branch_22: 
    %temp_2 = icmp ne i32 %s_16, 0, !Stack !{ !"Stack()" } 
    br i1 %temp_2, label %loop_8, label %loop_8.end

  loop_8.end: 
    br label %box_23

  box_23: 
    %s_17 = load i32, i32* %local_2, !Stack !{ !"Stack((s_17, W32Int()))" } 
    br label %box_24

  box_24: 
    %temp_5 = add i32 16, %s_17, !Stack !{ !"Stack((s_18, W32Int()))" } 
    %temp_3 = getelementptr inbounds [128 x i8], [128 x i8]* @mem, i32 0, i32 %temp_5, !Stack !{ !"Stack((s_18, W32Int()))" } 
    %temp_4 = bitcast i8* %temp_3 to i32*, !Stack !{ !"Stack((s_18, W32Int()))" } 
    %s_18 = load i32, i32* %temp_4, !Stack !{ !"Stack((s_18, W32Int()))" } 

    br label %box_25

  box_25: 
    %s_19 = add i32 0, 4, !Stack !{ !"Stack((s_19, W32Int()), (s_18, W32Int()))" } 
    br label %box_26

  box_26: 
    %s_20 = icmp eq i32 %s_18, %s_19, !Stack !{ !"Stack()" } 
    %s_21 = zext i1 %s_20 to i32
    br label %if_27

  if_27: 
    %temp_6 = icmp ne i32 %s_21, 0, !Stack !{ !"Stack()" } 
    br i1 %temp_6, label %box_28, label %box_32

  box_28: 
    %s_22 = load i32, i32* %local_1, !Stack !{ !"Stack((s_22, W32Int()))" } 
    br label %box_29

  box_29: 
    store i32 %s_22, i32* @Global_2, !Stack !{ !"Stack()" } 
    br label %box_30

  box_30: 
    %s_23 = add i32 0, 0, !Stack !{ !"Stack((s_23, W32Int()))" } 
    br label %box_31

  box_31: 
    br label %if_27_cond.end

  box_32: 
    call void (...) @__VERIFIER_error() #2
    br label %if_27_cond.end

  if_27_cond.end: 
    br label %box_33

  box_33: 
    %s_24 = add i32 0, 0, !Stack !{ !"Stack((s_24, W32Int()))" } 
    br label %func_2_exit

  func_2_exit: 
    ret i32 %s_24

} 

declare void @abort(i32 ) 

declare void @__VERIFIER_error(...) #1

attributes #1 = { noreturn "correctly-rounded-divide-sqrt-fp-math"="false" "disable-tail-calls"="false" "less-precise-fpmad"="false" "no-frame-pointer-elim"="true" "no-frame-pointer-elim-non-leaf" "no-infs-fp-math"="false" "no-nans-fp-math"="false" "no-signed-zeros-fp-math"="false" "no-trapping-math"="false" "stack-protector-buffer-size"="8" "target-cpu"="x86-64" "target-features"="+fxsr,+mmx,+sse,+sse2,+x87" "unsafe-fp-math"="false" "use-soft-float"="false" }
attributes #2 = { noreturn }
```

As an example in this code snippet regarding pointers, using an i32:

```
%temp_0 = getelementptr inbounds [128 x i8], [128 x i8]* @mem, i32 0, i32 %s_9
```

I run:

```sh
opt -always-inline -O2 -S output.ll > output-optimized.ll
```

With this version of opt:

```sh
$ opt -version
LLVM (http://llvm.org/):
  LLVM version 6.0.1
  Optimized build.
  Default target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  Host CPU: haswell
```

The final result is :

```
; ModuleID = 'output.ll'
source_filename = "output.ll"
target triple = "i386-unknown-linux-gnu"

@Global_0 = local_unnamed_addr global i32 0
@Global_1 = local_unnamed_addr global i32 0
@Global_2 = local_unnamed_addr global i32 0
@Global_3 = local_unnamed_addr global i32 0
@mem = local_unnamed_addr global [128 x i8] zeroinitializer, align 1

define i32 @main() local_unnamed_addr {
box_28:
  %s_0 = load i32, i32* @Global_2, align 4, !Stack !0
  %0 = sext i32 %s_0 to i64
  %temp_0 = getelementptr inbounds [128 x i8], [128 x i8]* @mem, i64 0, i64 %0, !Stack !1
  %temp_1 = bitcast i8* %temp_0 to i32*, !Stack !1
  store i32 0, i32* %temp_1, align 4, !Stack !1
  %s_9.1 = add i32 %s_0, 4, !Stack !2
  %1 = sext i32 %s_9.1 to i64
  %temp_0.1 = getelementptr inbounds [128 x i8], [128 x i8]* @mem, i64 0, i64 %1, !Stack !1
  %temp_1.1 = bitcast i8* %temp_0.1 to i32*, !Stack !1
  store i32 1, i32* %temp_1.1, align 4, !Stack !1
  %s_9.2 = add i32 %s_0, 8, !Stack !2
  %2 = sext i32 %s_9.2 to i64
  %temp_0.2 = getelementptr inbounds [128 x i8], [128 x i8]* @mem, i64 0, i64 %2, !Stack !1
  %temp_1.2 = bitcast i8* %temp_0.2 to i32*, !Stack !1
  store i32 2, i32* %temp_1.2, align 4, !Stack !1
  %s_9.3 = add i32 %s_0, 12, !Stack !2
  %3 = sext i32 %s_9.3 to i64
  %temp_0.3 = getelementptr inbounds [128 x i8], [128 x i8]* @mem, i64 0, i64 %3, !Stack !1
  %temp_1.3 = bitcast i8* %temp_0.3 to i32*, !Stack !1
  store i32 3, i32* %temp_1.3, align 4, !Stack !1
  %s_9.4 = add i32 %s_0, 16
  %4 = sext i32 %s_9.4 to i64
  %temp_0.4 = getelementptr inbounds [128 x i8], [128 x i8]* @mem, i64 0, i64 %4
  %temp_1.4 = bitcast i8* %temp_0.4 to i32*
  store i32 4, i32* %temp_1.4, align 4, !Stack !1
  store i32 %s_0, i32* @Global_2, align 4, !Stack !1
  ret i32 0
}

!0 = !{!"Stack((s_0, W32Int()))"}
!1 = !{!"Stack()"}
!2 = !{!"Stack((s_9, W32Int()))"}
```

As you can see, now I got i64s for mem access:

```
 %temp_0 = getelementptr inbounds [128 x i8], [128 x i8]* @mem, i64 0, i64 %0
```

What I need to get in the output is all those **getelementptr** instructions using i32s instead of i64s. Any ideas?

Comment: Try adding explicit target layout string and play with its values.

Comment: @arrowd, opt has no "-target' parameter, but -march. I tried specifying **-march=i386** to no avail.

Comment: I was talking about this: https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#data-layout

Comment: This optimization is due to `redundant instruction combine` pass. It is not possible to disable it explicitly.

Comment: Thanks, @arrowd, that did the trick. Especially the *p* option. I added **p:32:32**, with the whole line being: **target datalayout = "e-p:32:32-m:e-i64:64-f80:128-n8:16:32:64-S128"** and worked smoothly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @arrowd pointed out in the question comments, adding the **[target datalayout](https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#data-layout)** metadata solves the issue:

```
p[n]:<size>:<abi>:<pref>:<idx>
        This specifies the size of a pointer and its <abi> and <pref>erred 
        alignments for address space n. The fourth parameter <idx> is a size of 
        index that used for address calculation. If not specified, the default index 
        size is equal to the pointer size. All sizes are in bits. The address space, 
        n, is optional, and if not specified, denotes the default address space 0. 
        The value of n must be in the range [1,2^23).
```

The bit that specifies the pointers bit size is then the **p** option, which I added 
**p:32:32**, leaving the default for alignment and index size.

The final line is:

```
 target datalayout = "e-p:32:32-m:e-i64:64-f80:128-n8:16:32:64-S128"
```

Running the opt command:

```sh
opt -always-inline -O2 -S output.ll > output-optimized.ll
```

Produces the expected result:

```
; ModuleID = 'output.ll'
source_filename = "output.ll"
target datalayout = "e-p:32:32-m:e-i64:64-f80:128-n8:16:32:64-S128"
target triple = "i386-unknown-linux-gnu"

@Global_0 = local_unnamed_addr global i32 0
@Global_1 = local_unnamed_addr global i32 0
@Global_2 = local_unnamed_addr global i32 0
@Global_3 = local_unnamed_addr global i32 0
@mem = local_unnamed_addr global [128 x i8] zeroinitializer, align 1

define i32 @main() local_unnamed_addr {
box_28:
  %s_0 = load i32, i32* @Global_2, align 4, !Stack !0
  %temp_0 = getelementptr inbounds [128 x i8], [128 x i8]* @mem, i32 0, i32 %s_0, !Stack !1
  %temp_1 = bitcast i8* %temp_0 to i32*, !Stack !1
  store i32 0, i32* %temp_1, align 4, !Stack !1
  %s_9.1 = add i32 %s_0, 4, !Stack !2
  %temp_0.1 = getelementptr inbounds [128 x i8], [128 x i8]* @mem, i32 0, i32 %s_9.1, !Stack !1
  %temp_1.1 = bitcast i8* %temp_0.1 to i32*, !Stack !1
  store i32 1, i32* %temp_1.1, align 4, !Stack !1
  %s_9.2 = add i32 %s_0, 8, !Stack !2
  %temp_0.2 = getelementptr inbounds [128 x i8], [128 x i8]* @mem, i32 0, i32 %s_9.2, !Stack !1
  %temp_1.2 = bitcast i8* %temp_0.2 to i32*, !Stack !1
  store i32 2, i32* %temp_1.2, align 4, !Stack !1
  %s_9.3 = add i32 %s_0, 12, !Stack !2
  %temp_0.3 = getelementptr inbounds [128 x i8], [128 x i8]* @mem, i32 0, i32 %s_9.3, !Stack !1
  %temp_1.3 = bitcast i8* %temp_0.3 to i32*, !Stack !1
  store i32 3, i32* %temp_1.3, align 4, !Stack !1
  %s_9.4 = add i32 %s_0, 16
  %temp_0.4 = getelementptr inbounds [128 x i8], [128 x i8]* @mem, i32 0, i32 %s_9.4
  %temp_1.4 = bitcast i8* %temp_0.4 to i32*
  store i32 4, i32* %temp_1.4, align 4, !Stack !1
  store i32 %s_0, i32* @Global_2, align 4, !Stack !1
  ret i32 0
}
```

Comment: Note that you don't have to list all data layout items explicitly. For example, this is data layout I'm using in my own toy backend: `E-p:32:32-S32`.